# Iphone app - How to show the digital clock with current time

Tags: iphone, clock

Hello all I am working an iphone app where I need to show the current time in a watch That is there is a watch which displays the static time or static image . Then we need to find the current  time then move all the hrs,mins ,seconds pins such tht they should  set to their time.
Do u have any ideas to do this 
Thanks Everyone 
Here is my code:

//Calculate angles:
    float minutesAngle = (0/60)*360;
    float hoursAngle = (10/12)*360;

```
//Begin the animation block
[UIView beginAnimations:@"moveHands" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
minsImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(minsImageView.transform, minutesAngle);
hoursImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(hoursImageView.transform, hoursAngle);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

where as minsImageView ,hoursImageView are the imageViews set in the XIB who shows the static image

But its  not effecting at all..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have individual time values (it sounds like you've figured this out already) you can position your hands as needed.

This means it's time to brush up on your math skills. I think this'll give you a start:

A circle has 360 degrees in it. This means that for whatever time unit we get, we divide by the maximum value of that time unit to get a fraction and multiply the result by 360 (instead of 100 like a percentage) to get our number of degrees.

So, if we had 23 seconds:

> 23/60 = 3.8333
> 3.8333 x 360 = 138 degrees

Now we know how many degrees to rotate our object. I would get a designer to make you some nice hand images and put them in UIImageViews. Then, you can rotate them around their origins like so:

```
secondHandImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotate(secondAngle);
```

Good luck :)

**EDIT:** Let's assume that our hands are on 10:10. If we wanted to move them to 01:00 we would do something like the following. Tweak it as needed.

```
//Calculate angles:
float minutesAngle = (0/60)*360;
float hoursAngle = (10/12)*360;

//Begin the animation block
[UIView beginAnimations:@"moveHands" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
minutesHand.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(minutesHand.transform, minutesAngle);
hoursHand.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(hoursHand.transform, hoursAngle);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: Hi Aurum Aquilla , thanks alot for your response , I am also trying in the same way that is to rotate, but according to this can we able to show the time like whatever we like I mean only with 3 images( SecondsNeedle,mins needle and hrs needle images)? and If we show a  static time first like 10:10 then on clicking on any button we should move the needles to their time .. Thankyou

Comment: I would get the needles to set to their correct time now. Look up NSDate and NSDateComponents, they should have what you need. Just repeat the math function once for hours, then minutes. If you need it, you can do seconds. This sounds like a fun project, comment back if you need any more help.

Comment: yes you are correct , I can get the current hrs ,mins and seconds but for ex suppose the hrsImage I am taking is like showing time 10, then can I rotate it to anytime using this rotation formula without changing the image , same for mins ans seconds .. Do u get my doubt Thank u

Comment: If you have all the time stuff working, all you have to do is add animation blocks to rotate to the current time: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html

Comment: Can we achieve the same without changing the origin of the image like in a real time that is the hrs,mins and seconds start at same point then devide to corresponding times right .. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, easily. Just set the start and end points of the animation to the correct angles and then commit the block. You can even have a smooth stop and start animation that makes it look really slick. After that, you just have to handle the rotation of the hands with a method that runs every second.

Comment: Thanks but quite confusing , I dnt want one which runs every second I want something like showing a static time first then on click on button it should to move to current time .. if u dnt mind can u post a code which works like this .. sorry troubling u

Comment: Added it. Just mark my answer as right and upvote it if my code gets you rolling.

Comment: Hi thanks alot for ur patience , I will definately vote ur answer once I done , But I am not getting it to work , I posted my code above can you  check tht once thank u

Comment: the imageview taken for hrs is showing 10 where as mins showing 7mins like that .. do I mis following you

Comment: its rotating but its rotating the complete image not like a needle in the clock ..

Comment: That's because the default is to rotate from the center. You'll save time if you make your hand images like this: http://yfrog.com/gz3v25p So that you don't have to screw around with origin points. Just make the backgrounds transparent. And don't use MS Paint like me :P

Comment: Thank you I have used your image yes its rotating now from its origin but its not rotating consistently and does not understand how its rotating also ...

Comment: Lol, it's not rotating consistently because it's a terrible mockup I made in 30 seconds. You need to get an actual designer to make you a pixel perfect second hand that starts at the exact center of the screen.

Comment: Hi Aurum Yes I made some changes and make it work some how but sometimes it rotating in reverse direction ..  dnt knw y ? Thank u

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to show a digital clock, your life is SOOOO much easier than my previous answer related to analog clocks.

Create images with the numbers 0-9 and put them in your bundle. Have four UIImageViews in your UI in this configuration:

## [][]:[][]

*[ ] = UIImageVIew*

Then, you can simply change the images in each slot to reflect the time. If you use transparent backgrounds and high resolution graphics, you can create really convincing effects.

Comment: Hi again Sorry , I did not mean this